# How do you make a specific button SEND a specific value?

Tags: c#

Okay, this is probably one of the most stupid questions asked here, but how do I make a button send a specific value?

I'm trying to make a cash register program, using this example

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/176782-building-an-application-poscash-register-part-one/

Where we give the buttons event handlers, how can I make it so

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

will send a "1"?

On the other form, where I have placed my new keypad, depending on what button was pressed, it will send it to a Textbox:

```
private void registerKeypad1_ButtonPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
            textBox1.Text += e.KeyChar;
}
```

The guy who wrote the tutorial said he hopes that we are smart enough to know how to do this, unfortunately I'm not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Constructor of `Form2`

in `Form1`

```
Form2 f2=new Form2(1);
f2.Show();
```

in `Form2`

```
Public Form2(int i)
{
// here You will get Your parameters

}
```